# How can I capture default path of powershell Start-Transcript command for further to call it with Invoke-Item?

Tags: powershell, powershell-4.0, transcription

How can I capture the default path of the PowerShell's `Start-Transcript` command for further to call it with `Invoke-Item`? Is there a way to pipeline `Start-Transcript` to a variable and split the full path of the transcript file?

```
Start-Transcript | $TranscriptFile

Stop-Transcript    
Invoke-Item $TranscriptFile
```

Answer (score 1):

I discovered:

```
Start-Transcript | Select Path -OutVariable TranscriptFile 
Stop-Transcript 
Invoke-Item $TranscriptFile.Path
```

Comment: That's a good find (though the approach can be simplified), but note that the `.Path` property was only added to `Start-Transcript`'s output string in **PSv5**, as @PetSerAl points out.

Answer (score 0):

Simplest **PSv5+** solution:

```
$transcriptFilePath = (Start-Transcript).Path 
# ...
$null = Stop-Transcript
Invoke-Item $transcriptFilePath
```

While `Start-Transcript` outputs a *status message* as a string (which also contains the transcript file path, but it would have to be extracted from the message), that string instance has an added-by-PowerShell `.Path` property that contains the transcript file path.

Generally, you can query an object's added-by-PS properties via the `.psextended` property (which is hidden from tab completion and hidden from `Get-Member` by default):

```
> (Start-Transcript).psextended 

Path                                                                          
----                                                                          
/Users/jdoe/PowerShell_transcript.JdoesMachine.Q83psmn4.20170729002407.txt
```

---

**PSv4-** solution:

The `.Path` property was introduced in v5, so a different approach is needed in earlier versions.

```
# Remove everything from the message before the file path.    
$transcriptFilePath = (Start-Transcript) -replace '^.*?(?=[a-z]:[\\/])'
```

<sup>Note that the simpler `$transcriptFilePath = (-split (Split-Path))[-1]` will *typically* work, given that the file paths normally don't have embedded whitespace, but [PetSerAl](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4003407/petseral) points out that they *can* have, given that you can redirect the Documents folder to an arbitrary location and that usernames may contain spaces.</sup>

This works, because the default file path that `Start-TranScript` produces is mentioned *last* in the status message, with no trailing characters.
Note that I'm assuming that  *localized* versions of the status message also mention the transcript file path last, but I haven't verified that.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than *capture* the default location, you can *set* it to whatever you want with the $TRANSCRIPT global variable, e.g.:

```
$MyTranscriptFile = 'C:\MyFolder\PowerShell_transcript.'+$Env:COMPUTERNAME+'.'+(Get-Date).ToString("yyyyMMdd.HHmmss")+'.txt'
$TRANSCRIPT = $MyTranscriptFile
Start-Transcript

Stop-Transcript
Invoke-Item $MyTranscriptFile
```

To reset back to Powershell's default location, just assign $null:

```
$TRANSCRIPT = $null
```